# "Connect 4" code seems to not detect game piece

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a "Connect 4" game in python and my code doesn't seem to be detecting the existence of a game piece. I can't see why. The only thing I can think of is somewhere my code is getting the idea that there's still a "O" in the spot even though it's shown as changed.

```
import random

a = ["A", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
b = ["B", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
c = ["C", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
d = ["D", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
e = ["E", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
f = ["F", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
n = [" ", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]

play = True
turn = random.randint(0, 1)

while play:
    print a
    print b
    print c
    print d
    print e
    print f
    print n

    turn = 0

    if turn == 0:
        playerChoice = int(raw_input("Enter the column you'd like to drop your piece in:"))
        if f[playerChoice] == "O":
            f[playerChoice] = "@"
        elif f[playerChoice] != "O":
            if e[playerChoice] == "0":
                e[playerChoice] = "@"
            elif e[playerChoice] != "O":
                if d[playerChoice] == "O":
                     d[playerChoice] = "@"
                elif d[playerChoice] != "O":
                     if c[playerChoice] == "O":
                         c[playerChoice] = "@"
                     elif c[playerChoice] != "O":
                         if b[playerChoice] == "O":
                             b[playerChoice] = "@"
                         elif b[playerChoice] != "0":
                             if a[playerChoice] == "O":
                                 a[playerChoice] = "@"
                             elif a[playerChoice] != "O":
                                print "This column is full!"
                                play = False



raw_input("press a key to continue")
```

and here's the output:

```
['A', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['B', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['C', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['D', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['E', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['F', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
[' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
Enter the column you'd like to drop your piece in:1
['A', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['B', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['C', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['D', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['E', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['F', '@', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
[' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
Enter the column you'd like to drop your piece in:1
['A', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['B', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['C', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['D', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['E', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['F', '@', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
[' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

Comment: @FireArrrow5235 I think your if condition may have gone a little overboard.

Comment: Please, use a 2D list...this is unreadable...

Comment: In `if X == Y: … elif X != Y: …` the `elif` part is completely unecessary, as its the exact inverse condition of the if. So you can reduce it to just an `else`: `if X == Y: … else: …`. And then you can combine `else: if Z:` into `elif Z:` to reduce the nesting amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two of your conditions have a `0` (number zero) instead of a `O` (letter O).

```
if e[playerChoice] == "0":
....
elif b[playerChoice] != "0":
```

That being said, I don't understand why your logic can't just be:

```
playerChoice = int(raw_input("Enter the column you'd like to drop your piece in:"))

if f[playerChoice] == "O":
    f[playerChoice] = "@"
elif e[playerChoice] == "O":
    e[playerChoice] = "@"
elif d[playerChoice] == "O":
    d[playerChoice] = "@"
elif c[playerChoice] == "O":
    c[playerChoice] = "@"
elif b[playerChoice] == "O":
    b[playerChoice] = "@" 
elif a[playerChoice] == "O":
    a[playerChoice] = "@" 
else 
    print "This column is full!"
```

Comment: ... You know... I didn't think of it that way! I thought that if I didn't explicitly say "THERE'S A PIECE THERE" than it would do exactly what it's doing! All right, so that's two birds with one stone! Thanks!